# ejabberd node

Tags: ejabberd

While installation I am using user:admin ..domain:Admin-PC.I am able to start it.But it says that current node is : 'The name of the current ejabberd node is ejabberd@localhost'.I thought current node should be admin@localhost .Also I am not able to login to web interface usin user : admin@Admin-PC

Answer (score 2):

Node names in Erlang (ejabberd at a given machine, default localhost) have nothing to do with Unix users (admin on machine).
The node name define by default for ejabberd is just a string name.

Answer (score 2):

The default ejabberd installation uses 'ejabberd' as user part and 'localhost' as domain part.
So if you don't explicitly change /etc/ejabberd/ejabberdctl.cfg, ejabberd will use 'ejabberd@localhost' as "short name" for the node.

The short name is indicated by the option "-sname" in the erlang command.

If you want to change this, you can edit ERLANG_NODE inside ejabberdctl.cfg (the default configuration file has useful comments before that parameter).

In order to connect to the web admin interface, you need to:

- Register an admin account (e.g. 'ejabberdctl register admin mydomain adminpassword')
- Grant admin rights to that user for that virtual host (i.e. inside ejabberd.cfg you should have something like:
  {acl, admin, {user, "admin", "mydomain"}}.
- Login into the web admin interface with username: admin@mydomain and password: adminpassword

Again, as stated by others as well, the linux account you're using is not relevant for either the ejabberd node name or web admin credentials.

Answer (score 0):

ejabberdctl defaults node names to 'localhost'. You can override this by either editing your installed ejabberdctl's NODE variable or calling it with a '--node $nodename' argument.